# New custom close reason here on meta

Tags: discussion, meta, close-reasons

I've proposed the following new custom close reason for **here on Meta.Webapps**:

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

This is a direct copy of the one on Meta.StackOverflow (sorry Meta.StackExchange).

If we think that it's a good idea then it can be activated by another moderator.

Comment: I think this is a good idea.  I have tentatively approved it, but the new close reason can be deactivated if the community disapproves.

Comment: I think it's generally a good idea, but do you have a (closed) question or three where this would apply.

Comment: @Al it was prompted by the question about Web Apps being down due to the DNS/DDoS issues we had recently.

Comment: How does this relate to the DNS/DDoS?

Comment: @Jacob it relates in that that event was a transient thing and it no longer applies. If there is another attack, then that's a new problem.

Comment: Ok, now I got it !!